A python / Athena / Boto3 script referencing "all_agent_data_partitioned" database table fails when reading a Json array that is sometimes empty
I am reading json encoded data from the AWS Connect all_agent_data_partitioned database table .
I am specifically trying to read the currentagentsnapshot.contacts.contactid Array field.
When I read the currentagentsnapshot.contacts array my query runs successfully and I see populated and empty array entries as shown below
contacts  
[{channel=VOICE, 
  connectedtoagenttimestamp=xxxxxx,
  contactid=xxxxxx,
  initiationmethod=xxxxxx,
  queue={arn=arn:xxxxxx, name=xxxxxx}, 
  queuetimestamp=xxxxxx, 
  state=xxxxxx, 
  statestarttimestamp=xxxxxx}]
[]
[]


I have no issues reading other fields/arrays within this database table.
I only have issues when reading the currentagentsnapshot.contacts.contactid array field from the all_agent_data_partitioned database table using the script below.
The code is being run from Spyder.
I have included code below from the start of the script through the error.
I am receiving the following error:  InvalidRequestException: An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED
I am guessing that the error has to do with looking up a field value in an empty ([]) array, but this is juts a guess.
I need to obtain contactid values from the array when the data exists.
I am new to Athena/BOTO3/Python/Json...but am making progress.
Any help over this current barrier would be appreciated.
# Build an Athena Client using BOTO
import time
import boto3
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_SECRET_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
AWS_REGION = "ap-southeast-1"
athena_client = boto3.client(
    "athena",
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_KEY, 
    region_name=AWS_REGION,
)


# Use the client to run a query
query_response = athena_client.start_query_execution(

    QueryString="""SELECT eventid
                      ,eventtype
                      ,eventtimestamp

                      ,currentagentsnapshot.agentstatus.name AS agentstatusname
                      ,... other fields to return                     
                      ,currentagentsnapshot.contacts.contactid AS contactid            
   
                     FROM all_agent_data_partitioned 
                     WHERE eventtype != 'HEART_BEAT'  
                           and Other filters 
        
        """,
    QueryExecutionContext={"Catalog": "AwsDataCatalog",
                          "Database": "asia_ml_connect_db"},
    ResultConfiguration={"OutputLocation": "XXXXXXXXXXXX"},
   
)
while True:
    try:
        # This function only loads the first 1000 rows
        athena_client.get_query_results(
            QueryExecutionId=query_response["QueryExecutionId"]
        )
        break
    except Exception as err:
        if "not yet finished" in str(err):
            time.sleep(1.0)
        else:
            raise err


contacts is an array, so if you want to access the contactid from your example code, you would need to use currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0].contactid

John.....  Thanks for the recommendation.  I added the array reference as you suggested and reran the query.   I obtained the same error which tells me the SQL query did not finish successfully.   While your recommendation may still be needed.  It does not appear to be sufficient to resolve my issue.  Any thoughts on error logs that may contain more details or if blank array values may be a factor?   Thanks.

Does it complete if you just use select * FROM all_agent_data_partitioned?

Yes it does.   In fact, I just need to remove currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0].contactid and all the remaining references execute without issue.

And what happens if you only query currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0].contactid?

I went ahead and reran the query as requested with just this field reference:  currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0].contactid.  Got the same error as initially reported:    An error occurred (InvalidRequestException) when calling the GetQueryResults operation: Query did not finish successfully. Final query state: FAILED.

Can you provide an example of the output if you select currentagentsnapshot.contacts or currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0]?

For contacts I get...          contacts
[{channel=VOICE,
connectedtoagenttimestamp=xxxxxx,
contactid=xxxxxx,
initiationmethod=xxxxxx,
queue={arn=arn:xxxxxx, name=xxxxxx},
queuetimestamp=xxxxxx,
state=xxxxxx,
statestarttimestamp=xxxxxx}]
[]
[]                                                          otherwise I get the error message shared previously.

Oh! That's not JSON since it doesn't have quotation marks around the Keys and Values. Does the rest of your data have quotation marks?

The content is extracted from AWS per the script I initially shared.  It is ultimately written to a CSV formatted output file.  I also discovered it is stored in a CSV formatted Pandas DataFrame.  Based on your comments I am going to change the script to write the output to a JSON formatted Pandas Data frame and a Json output file.  This may take a day.  As soon as I am done -- or by late Tuesday -- I will provide you an update.   THANKS for your guidance.

First some clarification.  The script that I am running extracts AWS S3 content using Boto3 and Athena.  The default S3 bucket format is csv.  I was then outputting this bucket to a CSV file for viewing.  If I convert the csv bucket to a json format I find that keys are in double quotes, alphanumeric values are in double quotes and numeric values are not in quotes.     The query is failing prior to its transferring any output to the S3 Bucket.  It completes successfully if I reference currentagentsnapshot.contacts with or without the [0] with the results above. It fails if I add .contactid.

An additional few points:  (1) the script fails for currentagentsnapshot.contacts[0] but succeeds without the [0].   (2) The double quotes appear for primary Keys, but do not appear as you drill down into any hierarchies that may be present.      Not sure why the use of [0] appeared to work earlier.  I will need to look back and do some retesting.
